# WAMP Server 2.5 link on “Your Projects” not working

Tags: php, wamp

WAMP Server 2.5 link on “Your Projects” doesn't work. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Correct solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed that by updating 30th line as $suppress_localhost = false; (before is was like $suppress_localhost = true;. ) after update index.php file in wamp/server..